# Identity Server - Dynamically update claims based on selection within application

Tags: oauth, permissions, identityserver4

I have an application that uses Identity Server 4 and open id connect for authentication and authorization. I am now in discussion with the system architect that wants to do a few changes when it comes to the handling the user permissions. Within this application, a user can be a part of a single or multiple regions, and within this region the user can be a part of a single or multiple customers. These users have both regional roles, and customer roles. Within each region, a user can (in worst case, but very possible scenarios) be a part of over 150 customers with different roles in each one, which could result in around 2500 permissions in total.

When the user is browsing the application, the person selects different regions and customers that the user is currently browsing. This means, that a user has different permissions within a resource depending on what region/customer it is currently working on. My system architect suggests that these permissions should be stored within the access token being sent to the resource, so that the resource would check if the user is allowed to perform this action for the specified region/customer, and that these permission claims should update when a user changes region and/or customer. My worry is that these permissions seems a bit too dynamic to be handled inside of an access token as these may change multiple times during a user session within the application,

First of all, is it even possible to tell identity server that "User A just selected this region/customer, please update all of the claims in the token to match this region/customer", and if so, how would I pass the information of the currently selected region and customer to the profile service/user info endpoint (without having to model each region/customer as a custom claim)?

Second of all, my worry is that this is too dynamic to be stored in the token as this WILL change multiple times over the user session. Since a user signs into the application itself, and not into each region and customer, my suggestion was that we put this logic inside of the api/resource, so that when a certain request reaches the API, we check against our permissions database or cache too see if the action the user is performing for region and customer the action is. My understanding is that OpenID Connect and OAuth should not really be used in such a way that he is suggesting, but I may be very wrong?

I've read [this arcticle by leastprivilege](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/), which seems to address the same issues that I've stated, but my system architect didn't seem as convinced..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/) is the follow up of the mentioned article.

I can repeat what is written there, but in short: authorization is hard and permissions should not be part of the access token.

Unlike authentication, authorization is context specific and operates on different levels. That makes the access token not the best place for permissions. You also have the problem with updating claims, etc.

Basically the main purpose of IdentityServer is to handle the authentication of the user and global authorization (as in which client has access to which resource).

For authorization they've created the PolicyServer, where authorization has become a seperate mechanism to add permissions (claims) to the Identity. In the OSS version this is done with local middleware, but in the paid version this is a seperate server.

The authorization context is based on the client, resource and user. When you use this as the 'key', then you can add claims for this context. Making it very useful in a micro services architecture.

Also keep in mind that certain authorization can be resource-based. E.g. the existence of a user in the WebsiteAdmin table can imply that the user is a website admin. Or making a document available for the user only when it was created by the user.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was thinking in the same lines as you, and will do my best in convincing our architect that permissions should be left out of the access token, especially since our permissions are quite complex. I watched the video and read the article that you provided and it is very much in line what I am trying to convince them that we should implement.

Comment: I've implemented something similar (based on the PolicyServer) and for me this makes authorization a lot easier. Please let me know if I can help convincing them ;)

Comment: One of the arguments that our system architect has is that we are going to use a micro service architecture and that he's afraid that if each micro service has to check the permissions for each request then that can lead to heavy load, if say 100 microservices keep asking these question. But what I'm saying is that this is the very reason we want to use a redis cache (since we are going to use a redis cache for other non-permission based things). He seems convinced that using a policy server in such a way is considered bad practice for the micro service architecture.

Comment: @emmep I'm curious, does he have any sources on that? You could argue that authorization like this is a micro service in itself, having a single responsibility. Also keep in mind that authorization takes place at multilpe levels. You don't have to contact the service for e.g. static files, or where resource-based authorization is implemented. In order to prevent an overload of calls you should add some sort of caching. It's not just moving all claims from the access token to an authorization token. It's about redesigning authorization.

Comment: You can centralize authorization and you have far better control. Changes in authorization are almost instant (depends on caching), opposed to access tokens. You can revoke specific authorization quite easy in case the system is hacked, without having to shutdown all apps as authorization is opt-in. Which can also be seen as the downside. But the same counts for IdentityServer and I'm sure that with current techniques you can create a 99.99% reliable service.

Comment: I’ll ask him for sources of what’s he’s saying, as I am too very interested in why he’s claiming that the entire purpose of an access token is to contain your permissions, or else what’s the point? (His words, not mine). You mentioned something interesting in your comment, an authorization token. I suppose this token is generated by the policy server. Is this authorization token fetched by the client, and then passed along with each request to resources etc that trusts in that token? If that is the case, this sounds like exactly what we want to achieve.

Comment: I short, the ideal functionality for is being able to dynamically generate some sort of authorization token that contains user permissions for a selected region/customer, that a resource trusts for authorization of different actions for a certain user within its selected region and customer. This token should be able to be regenerated for a signed in user based on a new selection, so that it refreshes what region/customer it holds the permissions to. Can this (or something similar, please elaborate or point me to any documentation) be achieved using a micro service as the policy server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193350/discussion-between-ruard-van-elburg-and-emmep).